# Error submitting answer?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

Trying to upload a picture in an answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/39849/47206) question, I cannot upload images

[image]

but I can add links to images.

The answer looks fine (although not yet finished) - here is a screenshot of how I see it:

[image]

but when posting I get an error like this:

[image]

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I'm receiving the same error, just with submitting a comment at the moment. Perhaps there's a general issue?

Comment: I think your connection is broken or disconnected. Check the Internet connection and Try again.

Comment: @KasiyA - it was the connection to that page, whatever the reason, not my internet connection as such, but it was a temporary problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a temporary glitch for AU (U&L seemed unaffected) which went away on its own.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a temporary glitch for AU (U&L seemed unaffected) which went away on its own

Comment: @muru - please comment if you want it deleted